# What's the meaning of these debconf questions?

Tags: phpmyadmin, debconf

As you could see the result from `debconf-get-selections | grep phpmyadmin`:

```
# MySQL application password for phpmyadmin:
phpmyadmin      phpmyadmin/mysql/app-pass       password
phpmyadmin      phpmyadmin/mysql/admin-pass     password
phpmyadmin      phpmyadmin/setup-password       password
phpmyadmin      phpmyadmin/app-password-confirm password
phpmyadmin      phpmyadmin/password-confirm     password
# Configure database for phpmyadmin with dbconfig-common?
phpmyadmin      phpmyadmin/dbconfig-install     boolean true
# MySQL username for phpmyadmin:
phpmyadmin      phpmyadmin/db/app-user  string  phpmyadmin
phpmyadmin      phpmyadmin/internal/reconfiguring       boolean false
phpmyadmin      phpmyadmin/reconfigure-webserver        multiselect
phpmyadmin      phpmyadmin/passwords-do-not-match       error
# Back up the database for phpmyadmin before upgrading?
phpmyadmin      phpmyadmin/upgrade-backup       boolean true
# Perform upgrade on database for phpmyadmin with dbconfig-common?
phpmyadmin      phpmyadmin/dbconfig-upgrade     boolean true
# Delete the database for phpmyadmin?
phpmyadmin      phpmyadmin/purge        boolean false
phpmyadmin      phpmyadmin/remote/port  string
# Reinstall database for phpmyadmin?
phpmyadmin      phpmyadmin/dbconfig-reinstall   boolean true
# MySQL database name for phpmyadmin:
phpmyadmin      phpmyadmin/db/dbname    string  phpmyadmin
phpmyadmin      phpmyadmin/install-error        select  abort
phpmyadmin      phpmyadmin/internal/skip-preseed        boolean false
# Connection method for MySQL database of phpmyadmin:
phpmyadmin      phpmyadmin/mysql/method select  Unix socket
phpmyadmin      phpmyadmin/mysql/admin-user     string  debian-sys-maint
# Host running the MySQL server for phpmyadmin:
phpmyadmin      phpmyadmin/remote/newhost       string
phpmyadmin      phpmyadmin/missing-db-package-error     select  abort
phpmyadmin      phpmyadmin/setup-username       string  admin
phpmyadmin      phpmyadmin/upgrade-error        select  abort
phpmyadmin      phpmyadmin/remove-error select  abort
# Host name of the MySQL database server for phpmyadmin:
phpmyadmin      phpmyadmin/remote/host  select  localhost
# Database type to be used by phpmyadmin:
phpmyadmin      phpmyadmin/database-type        select  mysql
# Deconfigure database for phpmyadmin with dbconfig-common?
phpmyadmin      phpmyadmin/dbconfig-remove      boolean true
```

So what're these ?:

```
phpmyadmin      phpmyadmin/mysql/admin-pass     password
phpmyadmin      phpmyadmin/setup-password       password
```

Do this `.../mysql/admin-pass` is for `debian-sys-maint` so it's generated automatically ? dbconfig-common doesn't ask any question about these passwords, isn't it ?
I've searched phpmyadmin's sources, so it might be using debconf template for databases, isn't it ? SO after that I've searched debconf sources for this template and there were these lines for `admin-pass` ([i.e. here](https://sources.debian.org/src/dbconfig-common/2.0.9/dpkg/common/?hl=898#L886)), but it might be likely more effective if here would be someone who knows exactly what they mean.

Best regards,
V7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested and can confirm:

- `phpmyadmin/mysql/admin-pass` is the mysql root account password
- `phpmyadmin/mysql/app-pass` (and `phpmyadmin/app-password-confirm`) is the `phpmyadmin@localhost` account password

I guess (but I have no evidence) that:

- `phpmyadmin/password-confirm` is the same as `phpmyadmin/app-password-confirm`
- `phpmyadmin/setup-password` is the `debian-sys-maint` account password

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by "account password" ?

Comment: @V.7 by "account password" I mean the password of the designated user's account. Either the root account, the phpmyadmin account or the debian-sys-maint account.